# How to add the flair on wordpress blog

Tags: support

Anybody know about the plugin which we will use to add the SP.Se flair into the wordpress. I tried to find it but no luck.

Anybody know, how to add the flair in wordpress blog?

Comment: Is there a specific Wordpress plugin for this? I thought you where supposed to just use the regular code snippet from your profile page, but it would be sweet with a native widget maybe

Comment: i am not developer so i dont know...could you please guide me?

Comment: You find the script snippet under "Edit profile & settings" -> "Flair". You will need to embed it in a Wordpress page, I think it can be done by jut editing the HTML source of a post or page in Wordpress but it was some time since it worked with that so I might remember wrong

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely no need for a plugin, you can do this with out of the box Wordpress. Go to [this](http://stackexchange.com/users/3761194/waqas-sarwar-mcse?tab=flair) link to see the snippet for your flair. You want to copy and paste the snippet you see at the bottom:

```
<a href="http://stackexchange.com/users/3761194/waqas-sarwar-mcse"><img src="http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3761194.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for Waqas Sarwar MCSE on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" title="profile for Waqas Sarwar MCSE on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" /></a>
```

Once you've done that log into Wordpress and go to `Appearance` and then under Appearance go to `Widgets`. From the left hand column look for the `Text` widget and drag it into the Widget area that you would like it to display. You can then paste your HTML (from above) into the text field, save and update, and it will display on the page.

Comment: Great I was looking for it since long time.. It worked for me.

Comment: @AsadRefai Great! Glad I could help. Could you please accept as the answer for future visitors then?

Comment: I cannot accept this as an answer because the question is not asked by me. I have up voted though.